# 'date' is not defined javascript react -convert js to react

Tags: reactjs

Not to sure why, but i am getting an error saying that the date is undefined. COuld someone help me out please?

```
let result = {};

let dates = [
"2020-10-20T10:28:20",
"2020-09-20T10:28:20",
"2020-08-20T10:28:20",
"2020-10-20T10:28:20",
"2020-09-20T10:28:20",
]


for (date of dates){
result[date.split('-')[1]] = 1 + (result[date.split('-')[1]] || 0);
}
console.log(result)
```

Updated code:

```
let dates = [
"2020-10-20T10:28:20",
"2020-09-20T10:28:20",
"2020-08-20T10:28:20",
"2020-10-20T10:28:20",
"2020-09-20T10:28:20",
]



dates.forEach(date=> {
  result[date.split('-')[1]] = 1 + (result[date.split('-')[1]] || 0);

})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: maybe for-of loop is an ES6 functionality and your env doesn't support that. Try using `forEach` instead like so: `dates.forEach(date=>....rest of the logic here)`

Comment: hey, thanks, could I also use a map? what would be the difference? could you also please show me how you would convert it? thanks!

Comment: `map` will give you back an array whereas `forEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: its coming back with  a date.split is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `forEach` like so:

```js
dates.forEach(date=>{
  result[date.split('-')[1]] = 1 + (result[date.split('-')[1]] || 0);
});
```

```js
let result = {};
let dates = [
"2020-10-20T10:28:20",
"2020-09-20T10:28:20",
"2020-08-20T10:28:20",
"2020-10-20T10:28:20",
"2020-09-20T10:28:20",
]



dates.forEach(date=> {
  result[date.split('-')[1]] = 1 + (result[date.split('-')[1]] || 0);

})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: hey, thanks. getting a date.split is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: I have added a code snippet here and it seems to be working. could you share what kind of environment are you using for testing.